# Firestore rules work in simulator but failed when reading documents from angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

All rules are working fine in simulator but not through app. I have been following youtube channel Fireship's video on google signin  with custom data angluar [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP5zw7fjQgo&ab_channel=Fireship).

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

My authservice

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private ngAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) { 
    this.user$ = this.ngAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => user ? this.userRef(user).valueChanges() : of(null)),
    );
  }

  private userRef({ uid }): AngularFirestoreDocument {
    return this.firestore.doc<User>(`users/${uid}`);
  }
}
```

Using in html

```
<img *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user" [src]="user.photoURL" alt="user">
```

[image: error details]

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `user` object to `userRef`. Try modifying the argument.

```
              :
      switchMap(user => user ? this.userRef(user.uid).valueChanges() : 
              :

  private userRef(uid: string): AngularFirestoreDocument {
    return this.firestore.doc<User>(`users/${uid}`);
  }
```

Comment: Still not working, I believe it is more problem with firebase rules. But can not figure out what is wrong in the rules.

Comment: add `console.log(uid);` into `userRef` and check the `uid` is correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct, the rules are working fine in firestore simulator but not in app

Comment: Try testing your app with the firestore rules set to dev mode (eg. `allow read, write: if true`). This will tell you whether the code is fine or if it's the rules.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question, the error was in firebase SDK.
At 1 jul, 2021, firebase team released new firebase sdk v8.7.0 that fixes the issue

see the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#8.7.0)